# por que me da: Acceso denegado al Hacer SaveAs de SLDocument C#

Tags: c#, excel

Buen día compañeros.

Eh estado intentando crear un archivo Excel, hasta ahí todo bien no e tenido problemas pero al momento de darle el SaveAs me tira un error.

***System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso '***

estoy usando la libreria
SpreadSheetLight

el código que tengo es el siguiente.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //para generar el excel
            generarExcel(); 
        }

public void generarExcel()
        {
            SLDocument sl = new SLDocument();
            sl.SetCellValue("A1","hola mundo");

            sl.SaveAs("D:/descargas/guarda");
            

        }
```

esta es una función que mando a llamar en un botón.

si en el saveAs pongo solamente el nombre del archivo lo genera correctamente pero se va a la carpeta donde se compila el programa y me gustaría guardarlo dentro de una carpeta o ruta especifica.

Ustedes que saben más y tienen más experiencia. ¿me podrían ayudar?

Comment: ¿Has leído sobre permisos de carpetas?

Comment: @fredyfx no... ¿Me podrías decir cómo es eso ?

Comment: Básicamente, cada carpeta tiene permisos y cuando un programa está por usar algo de una carpeta, si dicha carpeta tiene permisos para todos **excepto** para el usuario del programa, el mensaje de error: `UnauthorizedAccessException` se presentará. No me gusta limitar a la gente, se libre, explora, click y a leer para más detalles: https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=ystem.UnauthorizedAccessException%3A%20%27Acceso%20denegado%20a%20la%20ruta%20de%20acceso%20%27&addon=firefox&addonversion=4.1.0&method=topbar Espero lo tomes a bien el comentario y el enlace. Saludos.

Comment: @fredyfx gracias ... lo veré

Comment: Hola, cambia tus "/" por "\" y comentas. Saludos.

Comment: @AbrahamValencia gracias lo intentaré